# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'childRecords') in syncfusion gantt when collapsing a group

Tags: reactjs, syncfusion, gantt-chart

I got an error when collapsing groups in [the syncfusion gant](https://ej2.syncfusion.com/react/demos/#/bootstrap5/gantt/default). I could reproduce it [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-pgu8va?file=index.js) with my own set of data ([stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-pgu8va?file=index.js)).

- The error full message :

  **TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'childRecords')**

  ```
   at e.expandCollapseChartRows (constant.js:13:25)
   at e.expandCollapseChartRows (constant.js:13:25)
   at e.collapsedGanttRow (constant.js:13:25)
   at e.collapsed (constant.js:13:25)
   at e.notify (dom.js:466:34)
   at d.e.trigger (dom.js:466:34)
   at eval (constant.js:130:22)
   at e.notify (dom.js:466:34)
   at d.e.trigger (dom.js:466:34)
   at d.collapseRow (constant.js:130:22)
  ```
- A screenshot showing the collapse action :

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/hzVsU.gif]

The error occurs only when there are two nested grouping levels which i think is allowed in the syncfusion gantt (right?)

Answer (score 0):

This issue occurs because the TaskID values in your data are not unique. The TaskID field acts as the primary key field in the Gantt. Hence, it should be unique for every record. Please ensure that the TaskID field is unique for every record in your data to avoid this issue.

Comment: Can you please show me where in the documentation that a TaskId is required ? in the Mapping task fields section , i can see that "id" is the name of the identifier for a task https://ej2.syncfusion.com/react/documentation/gantt/getting-started/#mapping-task-fields

Comment: I'm making that mapping for all my task fields, i actually use UIDs as names for all my fields at the data level. I only keep id: "id" with its same name as in the mapping json. TaskId isn't that an arbitrary choice for the id name in the data ?